# All Combinations Of Boolean Array

Tags: java

annoyingly this problem is quite easy but has been causing me a little headache today. (Apologies for the pseudocode)

Say we have two array lists of booleans, `a` and `b` where:

`a = [true, true, false]`

`b = [true, false, true]`

I am trying to generate a list of all combinations of the comparison between `a` and `b` with the following rules:

- If `a[i] = true` and `b[i] = true` the resulting `result[i]` should **always** returns `true`.
- If `a[i] = false` and `b[i] = false` **always** returns `false`.
- If `a[i] != b[i]` returns lists where one `result[i]` is `true` and one is `false`.

So the expected results for `compare(a,b)` would be (*I hope...*):

```
[true, true, false],
[true, false, false],
[true, true, true],
[true, false, true]
```

I have tried to do this in Java but cannot seem to iterate correctly, can anyone give me some help?

EDIT:

Another simple example for rule 3:

```
a = [true, false]
b = [false, true]

results:

[true, false]
[false, true]
[true, true]
[false, false]
```

Basically this is what i meant :)

Comment: Shouldn't the last one be `[true, false, true]`?

Comment: cant understand the output. and it cant be correct. false+true=false, false+false=false,false+true=false, true+false=false, true+false=false. if you combine every element from array a with every element from array b, you get 5 times false. but your output shows only 4 times.

Comment: 3^2 + false of array a gave two times a list and both true of array a gave a list, so you have 13 values not 12 in the result.

Comment: I'm also very confused about your rules. In relation to the size of the two input lists, how many lists is compare supposed to return and how many elements should be in those lists? `output[i][j] = ...?`.

Comment: I can't understand it either. How `compare(a,b)` returns a series of arrays of 3 boolean?

Comment: Sorry to confuse everyone, but just to confirm...this is NOT homework :)

I will edit my post with a better explanation shortly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursion is the classic way to solve these sort of combinatorial problems.

```
void resursivelyCombine(List<List<Boolean>> result, List<Boolean> current, List<Boolean> in1, List<Boolean> in2, int index) {
    if (index == in1.size()) {
        result.add(current);
    } else {
        if (in1.get(index).equals(in2.get(index))) {
           current.add(in1.get(index));
           recursivelyCombine(result, current, in1, in2, index+1);
        } else {
           List<Boolean> temp = new ArrayList<>(current);
           temp.add(Boolean.TRUE);
           recursivelyCombine(result, temp, in1, in2, index+1);

           temp = new ArrayList<>(current);
           temp.add(Boolean.FALSE);
           recursivelyCombine(result, temp, in1, in2, index+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Something like that :) The code will probably need a bit of tidying up as I just typed it in here untested.

Call it like this:

```
 List<List<Boolean>> results = new ArrayList<>();
 recursivelyCombine(results, new ArrayList<Boolean>(), in1, in2, 0);
```

Comment: I have yet to test this thoroughly, but it does seem you understood what I was trying to get across! This looks almost certainly the correct solution, but once verified I will get back to you and mark the answer as accepted if applicable :)

Answer (score 2):

I would say recursion. I don't know what is your goal in performance and how long will be the arrays but I would do something like the following:

**1, step**: create an array where some elements are fixed and some are marked as ambiguous by your rules, like this:

```
[Boolean.True, null, null]
```

This means where is `null` there should be either true **and** false.

**2, step**: in a method search for the last occurence of `null`, change it to `Boolean.True` and call the same method with this array. In the next line change it to `Boolean.False` and call the same method with it again. In this new calls there will be one less null element and you get the array with both `Boolean.True` and `Boolean.False` element in the ambiguous space.

**3, step**: in this method also check whether there is no more `null` value in the array and write it to the output if there is none.

Of course instead of `Boolean` and `null` values you can use something else or more meaningful objects and you can do it in an iterative way also but I don't know the details of your problem.

Hope I could help.